# Power query merge tables any-to-any

Tags: excel, powerquery, cartesian-product

I new in MS Excel Power Query and i cant finde solution in google for this problem.

Join tables any-to-any row

```
Table1        Table2
+-----+       +-----+
|  A  |       |  1  |
|  B  |       |  2  |
+-----+       +-----+
```

Merge **Table1** and **Table2** to **Table3**

```
Table3
+-----+-----+
|  A  |  1  |
|  A  |  2  |
|  B  |  1  |
|  B  |  2  |
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: There are various ways of creating **Cartesian Product** tables in Excel; one which involves Power Query is at: https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2016/05/11/cartesian-product-joins-for-the-excel-person/

Comment: that's what I was looking for. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [link Hakan provided](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2016/05/11/cartesian-product-joins-for-the-excel-person/) is great, so I'll just summarize it here.

---

Starting with your `Table1`, go to Add Column > Custom Colum and simply input `Table2` as the formula.

[image: Custom Column]

Once that column is created, click the expand button and choose which columns from `Table2` to expand.

[image: Expand Column]

This should result in the desired table.

[image: Output]